# Key binding in Eclipse for Maven package command

Tags: eclipse, maven, package, key-bindings

I want to bind the mvn package command in eclipse. So I used the normal procedure to do this: Window->Preferences->General->Keys and then I filtered for Maven. The only commands that showed up were Run Maven Build, Run Maven Install, Run Maven Clean, etc. Run Maven package doesn't appear. It would really help to have a key binding for this command, thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have "package" in your LifeCycle Mapping of your project, as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662437/need-to-run-maven-package-to-update-unit-tests?

Answer (score 9):

The approach I use in this case is to create run configurations for the goals I want (`mvn package` in your case) and then use key bindings to access those run configs:

1. Bind Maven Build to your desired key

   - Note: it defaults to <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>
2. Create Maven Run configurations for your desired goals like `mvn package`

   1. Select your project, choose run > Run Configurations...
   2. Select the current maven run configuration for your project (under Maven Build > yourProjectName)
   3. Click the copy button on the upper left to copy the run config
   4. in the name section, give a meaningful name such as "yourProject--package"

      [optionally, rename your original config to something like "yourProject--install"]
   5. In the "Goals" section, type the goals you want such as "clean package"
   6. Choose "Apply" then "close"
3. Use Maven Build key binding, then arrow keys to select appropriate goal

   - Now, when you hit your "Maven Build" key binding, you will be prompted with a window to select your desired run configuration.  ***This window only appears when you have more than one maven run configuration!***  From there press ENTER and you'll choose your package goal!
   - pressing enter will select the first maven configuration
   - use the arrow keys to select other configs
   - name your configurations such that the one you use most is at the top

Now, to execute `mvn package` on your project, press:

<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>
<kbd>enter</kbd>

To execute `mvn clean install -DskipTests` on your project, press:

<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>
<kbd>down</kbd>
<kbd>down</kbd>
<kbd>enter</kbd>

---

I hope that helps someone...

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted over a year after answering. Using this approach, you can execute `mvn package` without touching your mouse (i.e. via shortcuts) as well as more complex goals like `mvn help:active-profiles clean install -DskipTests` which is my default mvn command, with as few as 3 key strokes.